# How to delete an entire dictionary if a key value pair is the same from another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would you guys go abt creating a script where it deletes an entire dictionary if one of the values in the dictionary is the same as another dictionary?

```
dict_1 = {'_id': {'$oid': 'hi'}, 'navigator': {'CodeName': 'Web', 'appName': 'Netscape'}}
dict_2 = {'_id': {'$oid': 'bye'}, 'navigator': {'CodeName': 'Web', 'appName': 'Netscape'}}
dict_3 = {'_id': {'$oid': 'hello'}, 'navigator': {'Name': 'Fire', 'Name': 'scape'}}

list_dict = [dict_1, dict_2, dict_3]
```

Because dict_1 and dict_2 has both `'navigator': {'CodeName': 'Web', 'appName': 'Netscape'}}` I just want one of them. So I want to delete one of these dictionaries and keep the other

I want my output to be:

```
[{'_id': {'$oid': 'hi'}, 'navigator': {'CodeName': 'Web', 'appName': 'Netscape'}}, {'_id': {'$oid': 'hello'}, 'navigator': {'Name': 'Fire', 'Name': 'scape'}}]
# [dict_1, dict_3]
```

Comment: can you please add the exact expected output for the input?

Comment: Also what is the _input_? `dict 1` is not a valid Python identifier. Is it a variable name? Another dictionary key?

Comment: It was just an example, not an actual code.

Comment: what if `dict_4 = {a:1,b:4}`, do you want to ignore dict_4 as value of a is already in `dict_1`? Or are you just looking for values only?

Comment: Also, can you please share what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the names of dictionaries will always be `dict_n` where n ranges from 1 thru the number of dictionaries, here's the answer.

Also assuming that you are only interested in the unique value of `b`, the below code should work.

**Code:**

```
dict_1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dict_2 = {'a': 2, 'b': 2}
dict_3 = {'a': 3, 'b': 3}
dict_4 = {'a': 4, 'b': 4}

list_of_dicts = [dict_1,dict_2,dict_3,dict_4]
vals_of_dicts = [list(d.values())[1] for d in list_of_dicts]
x = ['dict '+str(i+1) for i,v in enumerate(vals_of_dicts) if v not in vals_of_dicts[:i]]
print (x)
```

The output of this will be:

```
['dict 1', 'dict 3', 'dict 4']
```

However, if you do want to remove the dictionary itself from the original list, then you can replace the `x = [....]` code with:

```
[list_of_dicts.pop(i) for i,v in enumerate(vals_of_dicts) if v in vals_of_dicts[:i]]
print (list_of_dicts)
```

No need to assign to x.

This will print out the actual dictionaries without the duplicate values in `b`:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 4}]
```

Comment: Thank you for this! But what about nested dictionaries?

Comment: Please put your question clearly so we can know what you are asking. Your question was about 3 dictionaries and you wanted to eliminate the duplicate. The response is for that. The more information you share, the more clear and close we get to what you want.

Comment: I updated the code. I hope that is more specific.

Answer (score 0):

To provide an answer, I need more details to your question:

1. what is `dict 1`? There is a syntax error as variables cannot be numbers
2. it is not clear in your question, which one should be kept in case b is the same and
3. a and b are used but not declared.

Deleting a dictionary can be done using `del dict_name`.

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
del dict1
```